# Check file size in hdfs

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I am able to retrieve the size of a hdfs file using the following command :

```
hadoop fs -du -s /user/demouser/first/prod123.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

which is giving me the output as 82(which is in bytes).
Now i want to merge this file with another file only if its size is less that 100 MB. I am using shell script to write all these commands in a single file.
How do I convert it into MB and then compare the size? Is there any specific command for that?

Comment: can you try to run `hadoop fs -du -sm /user/demouser/first/prod123.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1` it should be in MB.

Comment: no, it is saying "-du: Illegal option -sm"

Answer (score 3):

Simply use :

> **hdfs dfs -du -h /path/to/file**

I tried the same on my cluster by copying your command. Only possible mistake is that you're using *hadoop fs*, just use ***hdfs dfs*** and make sure you're logged in as a HDFS user.

Comment: I am already getting the file size .. but the problem is i am getting it in bytes .. i want it in MB. Any approach for that ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use -h tag(for human-readable form) in your command. It will give you the file size with KB, MB, GB. I have updated my answer.